# IF condition not working with Android CheckBox

Tags: java, android, checkbox

```
if ((Problem != null && !notokcheckbox.isChecked()) || (Problem!=null && !ressolvedcheckbox.isChecked())) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Enable Ok Or Not/Ok", 100000).show();
} else {    
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sucess", 100000).show();
}
```

I am trying to apply validation I have two check Box `notokcheckbox` and `ressolvedcheckbox`.

`if Problem != null` and nither `notokcheckbox`, `ressolvedcheckbox` is not checked then it should display `Enable Ok Or Not/Ok`

or

`if Problem != null` or either `notokcheckbox` or `ressolvedcheckbox` is enable then it should  Print `Sucess`.

while I am trying it with single check Box i mean its working fine but not with both.

Can u please tell me how  to apply with two check Box:

```
if (Problem != null && !notokcheckbox.isChecked()) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Enable Ok Or Not/Ok", 100000).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sucess", 100000).show();
}
```

working fine.

please suggest me how to fix it.

Comment: try to use || instead of &&

Comment: try this if (Problem != null && (!notokcheckbox.isChecked() || !ressolvedcheckbox.isChecked())){
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to display the "Enable Ok Or Not/Ok" text when both are unchecked, and otherwise "Success" (when either or both are enabled).  Try this:

```
if (Problem != null && (!notokcheckbox.isChecked() && !ressolvedcheckbox.isChecked())) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Enable Ok Or Not/Ok", 100000)
        .show();
} 
else {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sucess", 100000)
        .show();
}
```

If you instead mean it should display the "Enable Ok Or Not/Ok" text when neither OR both are enabled, and "Success" if just one is enabled, try this:

```
if (Problem != null && !(notokcheckbox.isChecked() ^ ressolvedcheckbox.isChecked())) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Enable Ok Or Not/Ok", 100000)
        .show();
} 
else {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sucess", 100000)
        .show();
}
```

Or better yet, use `RadioButtons` so only one option can be selected..

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying:

```
if (problem != null && (!notOkCheckBox.isChecked() || !ressolvedCheckBox.isChecked())  {
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

The expression below is true if `problem` is null and one of the two (or both of them) checkboxes is checked.

p.s. pay attention to the case of your variables, you should respect [java variable naming convention](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html).